# Convert to date Format

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

Hii,
     How i convert this QUERY of SQl into linq

`select convert(varchar(10), getdate(),104)`

I neeed a dateformat like: `31.12.2011`

Comment: Why do you need it as a LINQ expression?

Answer (score 4):

No need to use LINQ:

```
GetDate().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```